# ReferenceError: body is not defined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

tengo un problema con el código, estoy creando una web store y estoy configurando el backend para que descuente el stock al realizar una compra. Bien, al añair el código:

```
app.post('/api/pay', (req, res) => {
    const ids = req.body;
    ids.forEach(id => {
        const product = products.find(p => p.id === id);
        product.stock--;
    });
    res.send(products)
  })
```

Al ejecutar la web, funciona correctamente excepto cuando le doy a pagar, que devuelve la terminal el error dicho anteriormente

Comment: Como le estás pegando a esa URL? y que le estás enviando?